# How many resulting processes when using fork in linux

Tags: c, linux, fork

How many processes does this program make?

Is there any method or a general equation to calculate the number of process created by multiple `fork`s?

```
main(){
    fork();
    if(fork()){
        fork();
    }
    fork();
}
```

Another question: does `if(fork())` mean `if(fork()==1)` or `if(fork()==0)` or `if(fork()==-1)`? Which of these three statements is equivalent?

Comment: `if (anything)` is equivalent to `if(anything != 0)`

Comment: its not a duplicate it's totally different question

Comment: It's essentially the same question -- the answer explains how to understand what's going on and count the number of resulting processes. The only difference is the `if`.

Comment: After the first fork there are two processes.
Those two will then fork again (now there are four total).
Two of those (the ones in which fork() returns non-zero) will fork again (now 6 total).
Those 6 will then all fork off new copies (we are up to 12).

Comment: Due to the identical dup, by the way, I assume this is some kind of school assignment. :)

Comment: so @perh to rephrase what u just explain the first fork() will create two process one of them are the parent process second they will fork again due to the one inside the if statement so we have now 4 process two of them will fork because of `if` so we have 6 and finally all the 6 will fork because of the last fork wish give use 12 process ? am i right in this ?

Comment: Well, yes, that is basically what my comment said. It is explained in the duplicate question (which contains identical code)

Comment: it is but not like your explanation thank u appreciate it